# How to send a "multipart/related" content type in Actionscript?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, content-type

If I want to send the following format body in actionscript through http Post:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="END_OF_PART"
Content-Length: 423478347
MIME-version: 1.0

Media multipart posting
--END_OF_PART
Content-Type: application/atom+xml

<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>
  <title>plz-to-love-realcat.jpg</title>
  <summary>Real cat wants attention too.</summary>
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
    term="http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#photo"/>
</entry>
--END_OF_PART
Content-Type: image/jpeg

...binary image data...
--END_OF_PART--
```

How can I write the actionscript to send the "multipart/related" content type.
Please advice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that might help is using something like the AS3 HTTPClient library - they have helper methods for all sorts of request/response header manipulation that plain AS3 won't do. You can find it here: http://code.google.com/p/as3httpclientlib/

Doing anything beyond simple HTTP get/post is always a pain in Flash, and multipart POST is particularly tricky. If that httpclient doesn't do what you need let me know and I have one more utility I used to do this in the past. I can dig that up for you if you need it, just let me know!

Hope that helps,
myk

Comment: Thanks Myk, I will read and try HTTPClient library.  It is quite difficult to find information about the multipart/related content type in as.  Thanks for yours advice.

Comment: @Myk, if it is not very difficult to find the above mentioned utility, I would like to try it also.  Thanks.

Comment: I dug it up, it looks like this is not quite as robust as I remember it being. It's specifically designed to upload a JPEG with multipart form data accompanying it via POST - which actually looks like it is exactly what you need. Check it out here: http://code.google.com/p/nascomaslib/source/browse/trunk/src/be/nascom/flash/net/upload/ImageUploader.as

Comment: It used the UploadPostHelper that is for multipart/form-data.  It seems it is different from what I need.

Comment: Hmm, sorry man - that's everything I've got. Are you sure the HTTPClient isn't doing what you need? Especially that part about Custom Posts - I assume you looked through this documentation, but just to be safe make sure you check this out: http://code.google.com/p/as3httpclientlib/wiki/Examples

Comment: No need to sorry, I really appreciate for your help.  For the httpclient, it seems it will use the port 80, and I can't change anything in the server.

Answer (score 1):

[Inspirit's MultipartURLLoader](http://code.google.com/p/in-spirit/wiki/MultipartURLLoader) will probably help.
Haven't used it for multipart/related, but it has lots of useful functionality for adding files with different content types.

For example, you can add files with different content types using the addFile function :

```
addFile(fileContent:ByteArray, fileName:String, dataField:String = 'Filedata', contentType:String = 'application/octet-stream')
```

It seems to use multipart/form-data when it sends :

```
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push( new URLRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + getBoundary()) );
```

but you could easily extend this to use multipart/related.