# OData library for AS3 / Air

Tags: actionscript-3, air, odata

Does anyone know of an OData implementation in AS3 / Air?

Having done some searching I haven't found anything and ther isn't one nothing listed in the libraries section on the odata.org http://www.odata.org/libraries/

I am thinking of trying to port the DataJs implementation http://datajs.codeplex.com/, but obviously if this has already been done this, I don't want to be reinventing the wheel.

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't heard of one, but I hope I'm wrong :)

Comment: I tried to find it as well, found nothing.
There will be one problem with lib implementation. OData protocol has batch request that uses multipart HTTP requests. URLLoader does not support it from the box. Without batch request it will be very hard to update a lot of records (one HTTP request per one DB record).
Here are couple links for mulltipart MIME workaround:

[how-to-send-a-multipart-related-content-type-in-actionscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333569/how-to-send-a-multipart-related-content-type-in-actionscript)

[blog.inspirit.ru/?p=139](http://blog.inspirit.ru/?p=139)